# mongo query slow for simple query using PHP

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a very simple Mongo Query that I'm executing using PHP.

I believe the query is executing very quickly because when I run it on the terminal, it completes almost instantly, and when I do explain() it shows that it is executing in 1-2ms.

However, when I go to iterate the cursor and put the content into an array it slows down bigtime takes about 1 second to iterate over just a few records.

It IS using the index, and the index reduces the scanned objects to the few documents it returns.

I have other very similar queries running on this db that complete literally 1000x faster.

Following is the result of the explain():

```
cursor (String, 18 characters ) BtreeCursor vsid_1
nscanned (Integer) 7
nscannedObjects (Integer) 7
n (Integer) 7
scanAndOrder (Boolean) TRUE
millis (Integer) 2
nYields (Integer) 0
nChunkSkips (Integer) 0
isMultiKey (Boolean) FALSE
indexOnly (Boolean) FALSE
indexBounds (Array, 1 element)

    vsid (Array, 1 element)
        0 (Array, 2 elements)
            0 (String, 32 characters ) e11d0d96958a473e261933516489158c
            1 (String, 32 characters ) e11d0d96958a473e261933516489158c

allPlans (Array, 4 elements)
oldPlan (Array, 2 elements)
```

As you can see, it is using the index on "vsid" which is appropriate for this query. The size of this collection isn't small, but it ain't huge either (~250,000 records).

When I execute the query, I just loop through it using a very simple iteration to put it into an array:

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
  $vhit[] = $obj;
}
```

The actual time to execute each iteration is a fraction of a millisecond. The execution of the query is 2 milliseconds at most. But the process of entering the "foreach" loop causes a 1 second delay.

Any ideas?

Edit: The server is running about 8 GIG of RAM, but the entire database is only 745 MB, so it should be able to fit the entire db in RAM.

Comment: What is the query that you are executing .. and how many results are in the query?

Comment: The query is super simple: $ary_query = array("vsid_short" => $vsid_short,"vsid" => $vsid); and this example only brings 7 results.

Comment: How big are the documents returned?  Was suspecting the issue could be overhead of copying the results to an array (if you have a lot of documents, or they are large).  Is your MongoDB local to the same machine or are you connecting over a network?

Comment: the documents are about 1k each. The machines are local to each other.

Comment: It's really when it moves into the cursor loop that it slows down. The interior of the loop is fast. The query is fast. It's only when it moves into the loop that it has the delay.

Comment: Can you try iterating and printing the content of one of fields in the mongoshell and see if that also has the same issue? Figure out if it is a mongodb issue or the php driver issue.

Comment: @DenverMatt: It would be useful to try to isolate whether the problem actually relates to MongoDB.  I thought the problem might be your copying of the documents onto the array in the foreach loop, but I can't reproduce the slowness using your suggested numbers (~7 results of ~1k bytes each) with or without MongoDB involved.  Sample gist: [PHP loop copy test](https://gist.github.com/5ed8326bc281c9b8a0ab).  What specific version of PHP are you using (as reported by `php -v`?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the comments and ideas. I think the issue might be the fact that this query sits inside of a larger function that is looping on itself. I believe that what's happening is that as the function completes the first time it writes its data to the collection, then loops back around and tries to immediately pull the next set of data. My thought is that it is still writing when it tries to read the next query result. I've read someplace that Mongo "locks" the db when it writes. Which would explain a LOT about why this is slow.

Comment: Also, I've read that version 2.2 solves some of the concurrency problems. Perhaps I could solve this issue by simply upgrading Mongo?

Comment: @Stennie: I ran your loop and added a timer to it: time: 9.0122222900391E-5 (so, that's what I call "pretty friggin' fast)

Comment: One of the main concurrency improvements in 2.2 was moving from a global write lock to a db lock .. but I doubt that is the issue you are hitting here.  You could try capturing some [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongostat/) output to see if the lock % is high.  If the same query is fast in the mongo shell and slow in PHP, your issue is much more likely related to your PHP code or environment.  You could also try profiling with [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or similar.  For an isolation test, how about trying the loop with the array copy commented out.

Comment: We are logging time every step of the way and the bottleneck is entering the foreach() loop.  There is something very strange about using a Mongo cursor object w/ foreach in PHP.  It takes roughly 2 seconds to even get started but once in the foreach() everything is lightening fast.